# RxJS setting minimum delay for a request

Tags: rxjs

I want to show a loader when making requests in my app. But sometimes my server responds way too fast and the loader simply flashes for a split second causing an unpleasant experience.

In the past what I've always done is use `combineLatest` with a `timer` to create minimum request delay.

```
const request = getRequestPromise();
await lastValueFrom(combineLatest([request, timer(1000)]).pipe(mapRx(([x]) => x)))
```

What this does is if the server responds in less than one second, then just finish waiting 1 second before resolving. If however the server responds in 3 seconds, this code will **not** add an extra second.

This has been working great. But I just realized if the request fails (resulting in an exception) it does not respect the minimum delay. It resolves immediately and causes the unpleasant loader flash.

How can I have this work for both failed and succeeded requests?

I need to be able to still handle the success/error from the request itself:

```
await lastValueFrom(combineLatest([request, timer(1000)])     
  .pipe(mapRx(([x]) => x)))
  .then(() => console.log('handle successful request'))
  .catch(() => console.log('handle error'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use materialize and dematerialize for this so that there will be no error from the first stream ever, and only once the combineLatest has been resolved and you return the value from the request, you dematerialize it so if there was an error, it throws as expected:

```js
combineLatest([request.pipe(materialize()), timer(1000)]).pipe(
  map(([x]) => x),
  dematerialize()
);
```

EDIT: As pointed out in the comment, this doesn't work and here's why + how to fix it.

You can see in the console the output after `materialize`:

```
Notification{kind: "C", value: undefined, error: undefined, hasValue: false}
```

[From the doc](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/materialize), a notification of kind "C" means complete. So what happens here is that the request goes faster than the timer, and `combineLatest` only emits once both observables have emitted. Except that we've got a `materialize` on our request, and materialize will wrap all kind of events: `next`, `error` and `complete`. So here, even though the request is successful, it first gets the `next` one, then the `complete` one and only after that, the timer emits. Which makes the combineLatest emits has it now has one emission for each streams: A complete notification and the result of the timer.

So what we need to do here is to actually take all the kind of notifications, except for the complete one. Either `next` or `error`.

Therefore, after your `materialize` you need to add `filter((x) => x.kind !== 'C')`

So the final result should be:

```js
combineLatest([
  request.pipe(
    materialize(),
    filter((x) => x.kind !== 'C'),
  ),
  timer(1000),
]).pipe(
  map(([x]) => x),
  dematerialize(),
);
```

Comment: this is beautiful, bravo

Comment: @maxime1991 Actually it seems this has a problem. Ultimately `catch()` gets called even for successful requests. The error says "no elements in sequence, EmptyError". I've prepared a harness if you could please help figure this out. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-countdown-timer-component-rxl6wc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Indeed. Edited my answer to explain why

Answer (score 0):

I think you can wrap the `request`(which, I assume, it is a promise) with a `from` Observable and use a `catchError()` operator, so that the error notification no longer propagates.

```js
await lastValueFrom(
 combineLatest(
  [
   // Send the caught error as a 'next' notification.
   from(request).pipe(catchError(err => of(err))),
   timer(1000)
  ]
 )     
  .pipe(mapRx(([x]) => x)))
  .then(() => console.log('handle successful request'))
  .catch(() => console.log('handle error'))
```

Comment: Except that in this case you end up changing the return type of the request, which may not be ideal. For example, if OP uses that code in Angular on an interceptor, it'd change the return type of the request without having the bits of the code where you make the request enforce handling that. I've explained how to use materialize and dematerialized instead to keep the original behavior

Comment: @maxime1992 that's a very good point! Thanks!